# PHP exec on IIS not working through web browser

Tags: php, exec, iis-10

I'm working on an IIS 10 server and PHP 7.2 which I can manage.

I have a PHP file with an `exec($instr)` inside which call *soffice* thread to convert docx in PDF:

```
$sofice = 'soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir D:\www\CCAC_dev\model\data\001\temp\2021\05\ D:\www\CCAC_dev\model\data\001\temp\2021\05\geom.docx';
exec($sofice, $data);
```

The instruction works directly in CMD and It works also when I call it with:

`php -f file.php`

But when I call the `file.php` through the web browser nothing append.
I checked the folder rights when it should write the PDF file and gave access to IUSR.

Comment: Please share the contents of file.php.

Comment: soffice, if it's the staroffice/libreoffice/openoffice executable (which I'm assuming though you didn't say) is probably a GUI application, yes? If so then that's a problem. IIS's user accounts don't run in a GUI session. If the program requires a GUI in order to start up then it will never run in your web app. That's perhaps something you need to check. Also are you capturing any of the output from exec() to see if there are any error messages or anything?

Comment: @prieber: it's really simple
`$sofice = 'soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir D:\www\CCAC_dev\model\data\001\temp\2021\05\ D:\www\CCAC_dev\model\data\001\temp\2021\05\geom.docx';

exec($sofice, $data);`

Comment: @ADyson: there is no error message. I understand what you mean but so why it works when I ran the file directly with the command PHP?

Comment: Probably not in PATH for IUSR `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice` or whatever.

Comment: I did a similar project about a year back but with libreoffice and apache.  Assuming the server has nothing to do with this, I had a hard time realizing that libreoffice does not work headless in multiple instances. That could be a start.

Comment: Well a regular command line running in a user-facing windows session can launch a GUI window if it needs one. That's the main difference (aside from running as a different user, which it sounds like you're aware of - have you checked the executable path is valid etc for the IUSR account?). Can you show the contents of file.php please then we can see exactly how you're implementation looks.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. You aren't capturing or displaying the output of `exec`, so it's unclear how you can say there are no error messages from the soffice command - you aren't checking for any.

Comment: Did you give up?